# Entity Framework Core 3.1 reemplazar DbQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Trabajo con EFcore 3.1 deseo reemplazar un código que esta en EF6

EF6

```
using (var context = new BusinessContext())
        {
            DbQuery<T> query = context.Set<T>();
            includelist.ForEach(x => query = query.Include(x));
            return query.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        }
```

EFCore 3.1

```
using (var context = new CatalogoInquilinoContext())
        {
            DbSet<T> query = context.Set<T>();
            includelist.ForEach(x => query = query.Include(x));
            return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
        }
```

El intelisence me aconsejo que usar DbSet pero cuando ejecuto el código me da error que no esta bien castiado, ¿como lo puedo solucionar?

Saludos!!!

Comment: Y si le pones var y te fijas que tipo es realmente?

Comment: @gbianchi fue buena idea pero me guíe de https://www.coderepo.blog/posts/patron-repositorio-entity-framework-core/#disqus_thread era un `IQueryable<T>`

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione haciendo la siguiente modificación

```
using (var context = new CatalogoInquilinoContext())
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = context.Set<T>();
            includelist.ForEach(x => query = query.Include(x));
            return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
        }
```

Saludos!!!